# pyspark values are missing

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark_df = sqlContext.read
                     .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                     .option("header", "true")
                     .option("inferSchema", "true")
                     .load(storage_location + filename)
```

I have a normal csv file with multiple columns which contains space.
while converting it into pyspark datframe missing values is taken as empty string.and converted it as string column not as int column because age is int column.I want NA,null,empty space as missing values and not converted as string column

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast those integer columns so all the empty string converted into null values.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
spark_df =spark_df.withColumn("age", spark_df ["age"].cast(IntegerType()))
```

OR Try this

```
spark_df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header='true', inferschema='true').load(storage_location + filename)
```

Comment: if we can cast we can get the result.but i want it while reading only...in client side they wont know weather its integer column or string column.so i want automatically take it as correct column.not by doing casting

Comment: for this you just need `.option( inferSchema, 'true')` @karuppasamy Try updated ans.